# Nonworking QuickSort with InsertionSort implemention in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

I have tried to write a *`QuickSort`* method that implements *`Insertion Sort`* to speed it up with smaller arrays.

My methods for `InsertionSort` and `QuickSort` beautifully sorts the arrays, but when I start mixing them I get lists where some numbers place are switched when comparing to a fully sorted list.

First is the `Quicksort`:

```
public class qSort implements IntSorter {
public enum Order {
    RANDOM, FIRST, LAST, MYPIVOT
}
private final Order order;
private Random random;

public qSort(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
    random = new Random();
}


public int[] sort(int[] v) {
    return qsort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
}

// Sorts the elements of the subvector v[first..last].
protected int[] qsort(int[] v, int first, int last) {
    if(first >= last) // Less than two elements
        return v;

    int p = 0;
    // Choose a pivot element.
    if(order == Order.FIRST)
        p = v[first];
    else if(order == Order.LAST)
        p = v[last];
    else if(order == Order.MYPIVOT) {

        //The median of the first, middle and last element will be 
        //chosen as the median
        if((v[first] >= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[first] <= v[last]) 
        || (v[first] <= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[first] >= v[last])) {
            p = v[first];
        }
        else if((v[last] >= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[last] <= v[first]) 
        || (v[last] <= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[last] >= v[first])) {
            p = v[last];
        }
        else if((v[(last - first)/2 +first] >= v[last] && v[(last - first)/2 +first] <= v[first]) 
        || (v[(last - first)/2 +first] <= v[last] && v[(last - first)/2 + first]>= v[first])) {

            p = v[last/2];
        }
    }
    else if(order == Order.RANDOM) {
        int r = random.nextInt(last - first) + first;
        p = v[r];
    }


    int[] lowHigh = partition(v, first, last, p);

    qsort(v, first, lowHigh[0]-1);
    qsort(v, lowHigh[1]+1, last);
    return v;
}

/**
 * Reorders the elements of the subarray v[first..last] so that
 * all elements in v[first..low-1] are less than pivot,
 * all elements in v[low..high] are equal to pivot,
 * all elements in v[high+1..last] are greater than pivot.
 * 
 * Precondition: first < last.
 */
protected int[] partition(int[] v, int first, int last, int pivot) {
    int low = first;
    int mid = first;
    int high = last;

    while (mid <= high) {

        int a = v[mid];

        if (a < pivot) {
            v[mid] = v[low];
            v[low] = a;
            low++;
            mid++;
        } 
        else if (a == pivot) {
            mid++;
        } 
        else { // a > pivot
            v[mid] = v[high];
            v[high] = a;
            high--;
        }
    }
    int[]returnArray = new int[2];
    returnArray[0] = low;
    returnArray[1] = high;

    return returnArray;
}
```

Note that both implements `InSorter`, an interface to make it easier to test them later. It only contains the sort method.

And next is the method that mixes `Quicksort` with `Insertionsort`, named MixSort:

```
public class mixSort extends qSort {

private InsertionSort isort;
//Enum inheritet from qSort allows orders RANDOM, FIRST, LAST
private Order order;
//Arraysize for when to change to insertionsort
private int k;
private Random random;

public mixSort(int k, Order order)
{
    isort = new InsertionSort();
    this.order = order;
    this.k = k;
    random = new Random();
}

/**
 * Sorts the array in ascending order through Quicksort implementing Insertionsort
 * @param v     array to be sorted
 * @param first beginning of array
 * @param   last last index of array
 * @return sorted array
 */
@Override
public int[] qsort(int[] v, int first, int last)
{
    if (first >= last - 1) // Less than two elements
        return v;

    int p = 0;
    // Choose a pivot element.
    if(order == Order.FIRST)
        p = v[first];
    else if(order == Order.LAST)
        p = v[last];
    else if(order == Order.MYPIVOT)
    {
        //The median of the first, middle and last element will be 
        //chosen as the median
        if((v[first] >= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[first] <= v[last]) 
        || (v[first] <= v[(last - first)/2 + first] && v[first] >= v[last]))
        {
            p = v[first];
        }
        else if((v[last] >= v[(last - first)/2 +first] && v[last] <= v[first]) 
        || (v[last] <= v[(last - first)/2 + first] && v[last] >= v[first]))
        {
            p = v[last];
        }
        else if((v[(last - first)/2 + first] >= v[last] && v[(last - first)/2 + first]<= v[first]) 
        || (v[(last - first)/2 + first] <= v[last] && v[(last - first)/2 +first] >= v[first]))
        {
            p = v[last/2];
        }
    }
    else if(order == Order.RANDOM)
    {
       int r = random.nextInt(last - first) + first;
       p = v[r];
    }



    if(last - first <= k)
    {
        this.isort(v, first, last);
    }
    else
    {
        // Partition the elements so that every number of
        // v[first..mid] <= p and every number of v[mid+1..last] > p.
        int[] lowHigh = partition(v, first, last, p);
        this.qsort(v, first, lowHigh[0]-1);
        this.qsort(v, lowHigh[1]+1, last);
    }


    return v;
}

/**
 * A method that utilizes Insertion sort to sort given array of ints. 
 * 
 * @param  a        the array to be sorted
 * @param first     the starting index of the array
 * @param last      the last index to be sorted in the array
 * @return          the sorted array produced by sort() 
 */
public int[] isort(int[] a, int first, int last)
{
    if(a.length <= 1) //Array contains less then 2 elements
        return a;

    int save = 0;

  for (int i = first + 1; i < last; i++) 
  {
     save = a[i];
     int j = 0;
     for (j = i -1; j >= first && save < a[j]; j--) 
     {
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
     }
     a[j + 1] = save;
  }
    return a;
}
```

Note that mixSort extends Quicksort.

I can not figure out why my own MixSort doesn't work, though from the faults I have seen in sorted lists hints at problems with the Pivotpoint. Though since that code is shared with the Quicksort, such problems should not arise since Quicksort runs without failure.

An example of what a piece of array looks like after sorting is following:

- 19 19
- 21 21
- 22 23
- 23 24
- 24 24
- 24 25
- 25 22
- 30 30

The array correctly sorted is on the left and the same array sorted with MixSort is on the right. I'm not sure how to represent an array though, so this list will have to do. Note that the number 22 have been inserted later in the list.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What language is that in ? Java ? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part. Tagged and added in title

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it is still incomplete. Please provide the whole calling sequence of your methods and the setup of your input array such that we know which `order` (which should probably be called `pivotStrategy` you are planning to use. Maybe you can try print the output of different pivot strategies, then the differences might tell you something.

Comment: The problem was not related to the pivot elements, but to the arguments passed when choosing what sorting algorithm to use. I have provided an answer with the faulty code below. I should have been clearer with that in the description above.

Answer (score 0):

As you supposed I did not read all your code, but seeing something like

```
v[first] >= v[last/2]
```

in your pivot selection looks extremely fishy in my eyes. Last is supposed to be the end of a range and you want to look at elements `v[first..last]` in your sort (shamelessly using pseudo-ruby at this point, but I guess you get the idea). If you are given `first=100` and `last=150` you will look at element `v[75]` which does not belong to the elements you want to sort at this point.

Not having checked your code completely (and not having an example and how it goes wrong (hint, hint ...)) it is hard to verify wether this is the real problem, but you might give it a try.

Comment: Indeed, I see what you mean. I will edit the code and add an example. Though I suspect this will speed up the algorithm, it is not fixing it. I am still not sure where the fault lies. But yes, example on the way.

Comment: Everything have been added, but even with these changes it doesn't work. I believe that the fault lies somewhere where the choosing and the passing of the arguments to the sorting methods lie

Comment: Please do not prove me wrong without even compiling the code you post. Maybe you did, but if you write `v[(last - first)/2 >= v[last]` then I am sure that your code does *not* compile, since your are lacking a closing square bracket. You also missed to apply the change consistently as there is still `p = v[last/2];` (and a few other instances). You should probably introduce a local variable `int mid=(last+first)/2` and apply it consistently. (Only now I realize that you used `(last-first)/2` which is even more wrong than it used to be.) Maybe you should try to debug your program too.

Comment: I am sorry, when editing the code I accidentally wrote v[(last - first)/2 but it is supposed to be v[(last - first)/2 + first], which is what I compiled with. I answered after compiling and running and provided an answer without including these things. Sorry for the mixup. I will add an answer about what was wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two faults in the code, one is how arguments are passed between different sorting algorithms and the other is a wild -1

Starting with the first one: While the *`Quicksort`* method uses

```
public int[] sort(int[] v) {
return qsort(v, 0, v.length - 1);
}
```

to start sorting, the *`Insertionsort`* part would use

```
public int[] sort(int[] v) {
return isort(v, 0, v.length);
}
```

Since the -1 is handled in the code of the method. This means that when the argument is passed, it should be passed with a +1. otherwise there will always be 1 element that isn't sorted, which is what we see in the example. The other fault is:

```
if (first >= last - 1) // Less than two elements
    return v;
```

where the -1 quits the sorting not if there are less than 2 elements, but 2 or less. If these two elements are not already sorted it will create random faults of two unsorted elements in the list.